# How to parallel compute csv file store on each worker without use hdfs?

Tags: dask, dask-delayed

A concept same as data localy on hadoop but I don't want to use hdfs.

I have 3 dask-worker .

I want to compute a big csv filename for example mydata.csv.

I split mydata.csv to small file (mydata_part_001.csv  ... mydata_part_100.csv) and store in local folder /data on each worker
e.g.

worker-01 store mydata_part_001.csv - mydata_part_030.csv in local folder /data

worker-02 store mydata_part_031.csv - mydata_part_060.csv in local folder /data

worker-03 store mydata_part_061.csv - mydata_part_100.csv in local folder /data

how to use dask compute to mydata  ??
Thank.

Comment: Are your workers living on the same machine or on a distributed cluster?

Answer (score 0):

It is more common to use some sort of globally accessible file system.  HDFS is one example of this, but several other Network File Systems (NFSs) exist.  I recommend looking into these instead of managing your data yourself in this way.

However, if you want to do things this way then you are probably looking for Dask's [worker resources](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/resources.html), which allow you to target specific tasks to specific machines.